# How to upload file from local machine and move it into a specific directory of Joomla 3.6 (upload from config.xml)

Tags: php, xml, file, joomla

I want to upload and move file from my desktop to joomla component directory. eg: xml file need to hit services of specific API in a joomla component, so admin can upload this xml from component configuration and it should be moved into services directory inside that component, when admin saved configuration of the component. Is it possible in config.xml?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use any ajax call, like creating your own upload button by custom field there, or an ajax on save. Then afterwards use simple JFile::copy or JFile::move.